# the kernel appears to have died. it will restart automatically in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
word_count= count_dict(sentence)
```

only when i run this code I am getting the kernel has died error and all other codes are executing fine

I tried ruuning the above code but it doesnt work even after creating a new notebook

Comment: Beats me.  What is `count_dict`?  What is `sentence`?

Comment: What is the specific kernel? Pyodide? Ipykernel? What are the resources on the system where you are running this? You say 'all other codes' are executing fine' but what is the extent and complexity of code you have run before on this system? Or in this session? Is it expected to take a long time to complete or be computationally demanding? Please read and follow in the future [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular pay attention to the parts about writing a summary title about the **specific** problem and 'Help others reproduce the problem'.